Slack is black when sharing screen in call: Should I deactivate wayland?
I'm using Slack 4.39.95 (July 24), and Ubuntu 22.04.
When I share a screen on a slack huddle, the other person always get a black screen. However, I can share individual windows, though not all.
I can share a VSCode window for example, but not a document viewer window.
This redit thread advised to disable Wayland on my Ubuntu.
However, given the description of wayland as 'more secure and efficient' in this other page, I'm wondering if there isn't a better way to solve this problem of a black screen and lack of detection of certain windows.
Also, in the slack forums, supposedly the version of slack which I'm using should already support wayland screen sharing...

Ubuntu 22.04 has an older version of wayland, which may have screen sharing issues. If you have to use screen sharing on wayland, try 24.04 instead (note that the upgrade path has bugs. Please fresh install).
